# Free remote control software for Windows support

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop, remote-control

I am looking for a solution to allow me to remotely solve issues or offer help on my parents' computers overseas.

Requirements:

- Controlling the remote computer without logging out the local user.
- Audio communication with the remote user (not a deal breaker).
- Connecting to the remote computer unattended (time differences mean that sometimes I am only available to troubleshoot when they are asleep)
- Switching users on the remote computer (login/logout) without losing the session.
- Preferably free for non-commercial use.

Comment: Try TeamViewer, it is free for personal use.

Comment: Does it allow me to connect then the remote PC is unattended?  Time zones...

Comment: @Alex O When answering in comments please use the `@<username>` syntax, otherwise  there is not notification. Teamviewer can run unattended, but in my opinion I would never use this feature as it exposes a risk to the PC running on no matter what software you use. Additionally it is in my opinion bad behavior to access someone's PC without direct permission even if we are talking about your parents.

Comment: @Robert, "unattended" does not mean "without direct permission".  7 hours time difference is a thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Remote Utilities](https://www.remoteutilities.com/); it is free for personal use as you describe.

It provides [voice and video chat](https://www.remoteutilities.com/support/docs/voice-and-video-chat/) as well as your other basic requirements.